# kernel.core_pattern has no effect on vmcore file name

Tags: linux, kdump

On my RHEL7.4 VM, in `/etc/kdump.conf` I have set the path `/var/myorg/myhost`. In `/etc/sysctl.conf` `kernel.core_pattern = core.%e.%p.%h.%t`. The generated vmcore name is not as mentioned in core_pattern but it's location and name as `/var/myorg/myhost/127.0.0.1-2018-10-31-15:11:12/vmcore`.
Why does the vmcore name has no effect of `kernel.core_pattern`?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I came to the following conclussion. vmcore is the kernel crash dump and the dump path is mentioned in /etc/kdump.conf. On the other hand core dump is generated in the event of application crash. Core dump path and file format can be defined by editing kernel.core_pattern parameter in /etc/sysctl.conf. For successfully generating a core dump (application crash dump), ulimit for core must be defined in /etc/security/limits.conf file ( add this line to limits.conf: root    soft    core    unlimited. ) After setting all the parameters correctly, an application crash can be simulated to test.
The bottom line is,vmcore and core dump are two different things. kdump.conf and core_pattern has no dependancies on each other.